# singly linked list insertion issue

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was trying to insert element at end of a linked list, but if I comment the break in my while loop, it goes to a continuous loop, I'm unable to figure out why

code:

```
head=NULL;
node *temp=head;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    //temp=head;
    node* t1=new node;
        
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        t1->a=i;
        t1->next=NULL;
        head=t1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->next==NULL)
            {
                t1->a=i;
                t1->next=NULL;
                temp->next=t1;
                //break;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
}

temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    cout<<temp->a<<endl;
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is trying to traverse the new node you have just added again and again. Breaking the loop after the insert operation is correct here, otherwise the while loop may loop indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop runs forever without the `break` because `temp` is never set to NULL to stop the loop. When the `while` loop reaches the last node in the list, it appends the new node to the end, then sets `temp` to that node. So the next loop iteration sees that node, appends again, and again, and again, endlessly.

So, you need to `break` the `while` loop when the last node has been reached:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    node* t1 = new node;
    t1->a = i;
    t1->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = t1;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->next == NULL)
            {
                temp->next = t1;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

In which case, the `while` loop can be simplified to not need `break` at all:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    node* t1 = new node;
    t1->a = i;
    t1->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = t1;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = t1;
    }
}
```

---

That being said, this whole code can be greatly simplified further, to not reiterate the entire list on each iteration of the outer `for` loop, and to not use an `if.. else` to decide whether or not to set the `head`:

```cpp
node **temp = &head;
while (*temp != NULL)
{
    temp = &((*temp)->next);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    node* t1 = new node;
    t1->a = i;
    t1->next = NULL;

    *temp = t1;
    temp = &(t1->next);
}
```